# Memory allocation and deletion inside functions

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am gritting a big numerical analysis program where I NEED to optimize memory hardly.

In my program there is some points where I need to compute a matrix and then use it in some functions. Let's call the matrix `f`. `f` is `winSize x winSize`, a variable that is calculated previous of `f` creations.

I have several functions, this are the important ones:

```
double** getF(some params to get f,int winSize){
    double** f=new double*[winSize];
    for(int i=0;i<winSize;i++)
         f[i]=new double[winSize];
    /* 

    Some stuff to fill f

    */
}
void freeF(double** f,int winSize){
     for(int i=0;i<winSize;i++)
         delete [] f[i];
     delete [] f;
}
```

And the program goes like:

```
int winSize=computeWindowSize();
double** f=getF(someparams,winSize);

hiIamaFunctionThatWantsToReadF(params...,f,winSize);
soIwant(params2...,f,winSize);
iamJustCurious(f,winSize);

freeF(f,winSize)
```

Note that nobody modifies f, just reads it.

My problem is that this does NOT free the memory. I think the problem is in the way I handle f, but not sure....

My questions are:

- Why is this not working?
- What should I do to make it work?

**EDIT:**

How do I check that the memory is not freed?

I have to run this piece of code 1000x1400 times, and in few iterations the program crashes because there is no more free RAM memory in my computer... That may be a sign of not freed memory.
Then I tried to create memory OUTSIDE the function and then deleting OUTSIDE the function. 
In that way I can see memory being allocated and deleted. But once inside the functions I can see the allocation but never the dealocation.

Comment: How do you conclude that it doesn't work?

Comment: `delete []` is doing what it's supposed to do, promise.

Comment: i think your problem is you are not seeing the freed memory after calling your free function? and there is no other problem like mempry corruption

Comment: @KarthikT I know it doesn't work because I checked the memory being used by the program. I tried to do all this but outside a function and I can see the memory being used up and down in every loop, but once inserted allocation and deallocation inside their correspondent function I can see the memory going up but never down.

Comment: @Toms I may not see the memory... But I try to make 1000x1400 time this, and in few iterations the program crashes because there is no more free RAM memory in my computer... That may be a sign of not freed memory...

Comment: no problem in this code!!!

Comment: @Toms But the loop is just what you see... And there is not any other place in the code where I do new.... all the other variables are previously created or are mere ints....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it appears that there is too little information to say what your code doesn't work.

maybe it's in the code not shown.

but you can just use a construct guaranteed to work.

instead of

```
double** f=getF(someparams,winSize);
```

do

```
std::vector<double> f( winSize*winSize );
```

then instead of

```
f[y][x]
```

do

```
f[y*winSize + x]
```

of course you can define a function to do that indexing

and of course you can wrap it in a matrix class

but essentially, that's one way to make things work :)

note that the `std::vector` takes care both of allocation and deallocation, and it can also be resized and copied if you want

Comment: +1, my kind of answer. Side-step the unnecessary mini-problemms by providing a cleaner solution to the macro-problem.

Comment: Ok, probably that will be my solution, thanks.  But I am still interested in why my solution does not work.

Comment: +1. And since this is a matrix for numerical computation and all that, I wouldn't rule out a [valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) either.